# Finding Sum of values of a particular group in Table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL. The first one is Catalog with one of its columns as Category, and another table Stock with SP and CP as columns. I want to find the total profit of each category.

I am not able to come up with an appropriate query. Every query I try gives an error. Can anyone help?

```
select A.Category,sum(B.SP group by A.Category) as TotalSP,sum(B.CP group by A.Category) as TotalCP,
case
when TotalSP>TotalCP then ((TotalSP-TotalCP)/TotalSP)*100  
when TotalSP<TotalCP then ((TotalSP-TotalCP)/TotalCP)*100
end
as TotalProfit
from Catalog A,Stock B;
```

Note: negative profit automatically considered as loss.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Drew`Every query I try gives an error`

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.Category,sum(B.SP) as TotalSP,sum(B.CP) as TotalCP,
case
when TotalSP>TotalCP then ((TotalSP-TotalCP)/TotalSP)*100  
when TotalSP<TotalCP then ((TotalSP-TotalCP)/TotalCP)*100
end
as TotalProfit
from Catalog A
INNER JOIN Stock B ON B.catalog_id = A.id/*Write how your tables linked here*/
group by A.Category;
```

This query selects all catalog records, joins stock data to it, then groups results by category, counts sums in each group.

Comment: Thanks for the ans..@vp_arth